# iOS implement navigation lesson not saving

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm following Apple's lesson on handling Xcode.
I'm trying to save a new "meal" instance into my tableview by clicking the save button on my storyboard.

In my mealViewcontroller, I have the prepare function:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let rating = ratingControl.rating
        let image = mealImageView.image
        meal = Meal(name: name, rating: rating, image: image)
    }
}
```

And in my MealTableViewController :

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)
        meals.append(meal)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
    }
}
```

I've linked my save button on the MealTableViewController with the Exit item and selected the action segue "unwindToMealListWithSender", which doesn't correspond to the name of my func "unwindToMealList"

Is it the reason why, when I add an item and click the save button, nothing is added to my MealView?

I tried breakpoint but couldn't find a spot where the issue would be.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if sender as? UIBarButtonItem === saveButton {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let rating = ratingControl.rating
        let image = mealImageView.image
        meal = Meal(name: name, rating: rating, image: image)
    }
}
```